# MissingTemplate in Pages#home

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried opening my homepage blog on **localhost:3000/pages/home** and I got this error message: Missing Template` in Pages#home. I don't know what I'm missing. Still fairly new with ruby. I added an additional link in my homepage previously and maybe that's the reason. The code for my **home.html.erb** is below. Your assistance is sought and highly appreciated.

```
<h1>this the alpha-blog page</h1>
<h2>Spectacular Mountain</h2>
<img src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
<%= link_to "Alpha-blog", articles_path %> |<%=link_to"About",about_path %>


Action View::Missing Template in Pages#home
Showing /home/nitrous/code/rails_projects/alpha-blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #10 raised:

Missing partial layout/_messages with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:

* "/home/nitrous/code/rails_projects/alpha-blog/app/views"
Extracted source (around line #10):
8
9
10
11
12
13

</head>
<body>
<%= render 'layout/messages' %>
<% yield% >

</body>

Rails.root: /home/nitrous/code/rails_projects/alpha-blog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__148494832947707035_40406660'
```

My **config/routes.rb* looks like this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'
  get 'about', to:'pages#about'
  resources :articles
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Within your code you called

```
<%= render 'layout/messages' %>
```

but you did not include the file "_messages.html.erb" within the "app/views/layouts" folder. Simply create a "_messages.html.erb" file within the layouts folder and you should be good to go.